# Terms for different types of development

Tags: terminology, jargon

I'm trying to figure out the right terminology for the different types of software development

Right now, the only development term I know is "web development", but I've also done a lot of Java and C# development for desktop applications. Obviously this isn't web development, but I'd like to be able to group these under a single term that is widely known and accepted within the industry.

Would the term for applications on the desktop be "desktop development"?

Comment: Downvoter, I've edited the question. Perhaps leave a comment if the question still needs improvement?

Comment: Have you considered "software development"?  I know it is a bit generic, but I haven't seen "desktop development" on very many job postings or resumes.

Comment: @KateRoth-Matsudaira Yeah, I thought about that. However, I didn't think 'web development' and 'software development' was a good balance, since 'software development' could encompass 'web development'? Basically, I need to show on my resume that I'm good at web development but also good at Java/C#/etc desktop development - and I need it to be two different categories.

Comment: for the record: [this question has been discussed at Programmers Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3407/software-development-terminology-is-off-topic-here "'Software development terminology is off-topic here?'")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still see quite a few ads for Desktop Application Development. I think you might get more play if you specify the platform - Windows Application Development or OSX Application Development, for example, along with the languages (eg, C++) and libraries/frameworks (eg, Qt), so something like:

Developed applications for Windows using C++ in Qt 4.5

Answer (score 4):

Desktop Application Development or Rich Client Development come to mind...

Answer (score 3):

The classifications I've always known are

- Web Development
- Desktop Development
- Mobile Development
- Embedded Systems Development
- Database Development (Stored Procs, etc.)
- Client-Server Development (Not used as frequently as it once was)